# LuaInterface issue with vs 2015 RC project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, lua, luainterface

I am using LuaInterface to allow lua to be on my C# console application. I orginally programmed it on vs2012, and didn't have any problems. I did have to add this chunk of code to the app.config file to run:

```
        <runtime>
           <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
             <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.28.0" newVersion="4.2.28.0" />
               </dependentAssembly>
           </assemblyBinding>
        </runtime>
```

I am currently using the vs 2015 RC with .NET 4.6 and it is giving me this error:

```
    not load file or assembly 'lua51, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1e1fb15b02227b8a' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format
```

Also I did download the source code of luainterface and I was able to compile that code in vs 2015. Any pointers or solutions to this problem? thank you for your help!

Comment: First-level diagnostic: [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx). Second-level: Profile with [depends](http://www.dependcywalker.com).